# Facebook Open Graph does not scrape my website correctly "Meta Tags In Body"

Tags: html, facebook, xhtml, facebook-opengraph

We have a website which I should correct.
http://gewinnspiel.point-s.de/gw

I integrated the Facebook Meta Tags as described on the developer pages of Facebook.
But when I put my link in the Open Graph Debugger it says "Meta Tags In Body" and doesn't find the tags.
I can't get it work properly, maybe you can help me.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gewinnspiel.point-s.de%2Fgw%2F

---

**Update:**

Answer from CBroe is correct/good.

Here I found an article (german) which shows how to remove BOM from your files.
Because of the pictures, I think it is also helpful for no-german speakers.

http://simonstamm.de/kodierung-utf-8-ohne-bom/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on [See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gewinnspiel.point-s.de%2Fgw%2F), it displays:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html><body>
<p>&iuml;&raquo;&iquest;

</p>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

… and so on.

`&iuml;&raquo;&iquest;` are the HTML entities for the characters `ï»¿`, and those are what’s known as a *Byte Order Mark*.

BOMs cause more problems for UTF-8 documents on the web than they solve – so try and remove the BOM from all your files that the page is composed of. (Use “save as UTF-8 without BOM” or similar in your editor.)

Comment: I'm getting the same problem, I'm using TextPad and when I view the source the BOMs are not there.
It seems to Facebook is finding them but I've got nothing creating them. Do you know why Facebook is seeing them?

Comment: @RichardYoung: The BOM consists of characters (resp. byte values) that are normally not displayed – so that you “don’t see it” doesn’t necessarily mean it isn’t there. Make sure to save your documents as “UTF-8 without BOM.” If your editor doesn’t offer that option – then get a different one.

Comment: @RichardYoung do you have static pages, that are stored in just one document? Or are you assembling a page out of different sources? F.e. in a PHP system that uses include/require, the BOM could also be hiding in “sub”-files …

Comment: Could this be the cause of the problem?
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>

Comment: Not sure; but why are you saving your documents as UTF-8 in the first place, if the content _is not_ encoded as UTF-8? Or is it UTF-8, but your meta charset is lying?